# Copy specified subdirectories

Tags: command-line, usb, directory, cp

I have a bunch of folders in an external HDD and I want to copy a part of them. The folders have the following structure:

```
A001A
A003A
A004A
etc...
```

...and all the folders contain similar directories e.g:

```
HHZ
HH1
HH2
LHZ
LH1
LH2
```

I need to copy all the directories (A001A, A002A ...) with the subdirectories (HHZ, HH1, HH2) but with only the directories with H initial (also every files in it).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick (assuming all the directories in the current folder are A*** directories):

`cp -r --parents */H* destination/`

You should obviously replace `destination/` with your actual target.

Answer (score 0):

If your `pax` supports the `-0` option (and your `find` the `-print0` predicate):

```
find . -path '*/H*' -print0 | pax -0rwpe /dest/dir/
```

Would copy all the files and directories that `/H` in their path.

If they don't but you can guarantee file paths don't contain newline characters, you can remove both `0`s in the command above.